# How do I add a role/claims dynamically to the Asp.Net identity tables in Asp.net5/EF7?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net5

I am trying to create the WebAPI service for providing security using Asp.Net Identity in Asp.Net5/EntityFramework7. I have created a web application project using Asp.Net 5 templates. It has provided me with the template code for managing users. Now I am trying to do the same for roles/claims.

I have created a ApplicationRole class inheritingting the IdentityRole.

```
 public class ApplicationRole: IdentityRole
    {
        public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name, string description) : base(name)
        {
            this.Description = description;
        }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

My Web API controller class method to add a new role is like below:

```
 [HttpPost("CreateRole", Name = "CreateRole")]
        public async Task CreateRole([FromBody]string role)
        {
            var applicationRole = new ApplicationRole(role, role);
            var idResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(applicationRole);
            if (idResult.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "Role Created successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Internal error occurred"),
                    ReasonPhrase = "Internal error occurred",
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                };
                throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
            }
        }
```

When I try to execute this code, the appication crashes with the exception

```
 "A database operation failed while processing the request.
        ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
         Parameter name: entityType 
        There are pending model changes for ApplicationDbContext
        Scaffold a new migration for these changes and apply them to the database from the command line:

        > dnx ef migrations add [migration name] 
        > dnx ef database update
    "
```

It crashes in the line   var idResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(applicationRole);
The Quick watch values for the applicationRole object variable can be found in the [attached snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X9hf.png). When the above mentioned line is executed, the control goes to the ApplicationDbContext class and executes BuildModel() method. I haven't done any changes to the AspNetRoles tables, but still the application is pointing me to run the migration scripts, Can anyone help me on fixing this issue? How do I add a role/claims dynamically to the Asp.Net identity tables in Asp.net5/EntityFramework7 ?

Note: in the RoleManager object during runtime i see the error message as "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entityType", please find [attached snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lJsB.png)

Comment: In the Startup.cs file, in the ConfigureServices method, I register the User and Role Identity like below:  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. I need to add ApplicationRole also in the ApplicationDbContext class. This solves the problem.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
...
...
}
```

I got the solution from the post [How do I extend IdentityRole using Web API 2 + AspNet Identity 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671881/how-do-i-extend-identityrole-using-web-api-2-aspnet-identity-2)